# Warning when loading pysal library

Tags: python, sqlite, gis, warnings, pysal

I dowloaded `Anaconda` e installed `Pysal` through the nqvigator. It seems to work properly, but when loading it, the following warning appears:

```
UserWarning: The `dill` module is required to use the sqlite backend fully.
  from .sqlite import head_to_sql, start_sql
```

I've looked for a similar question on SO but could not find.
What does this warning means and how could I "solve" ( I know it works even without doing anything) it?

Comment: What exactly *is* your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I claryfied now